# Play Framework 2.4 don't accept "public static Result" for controllers

Tags: java, playframework

I am try to start an app using Play Framework 2.4 with JDK8 in Mac, when I download the base using ./activator new Project play-java the template code contains the next:

Project/app/controlles/Application.java

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

But when I replace this part:

```
public static Result index() {...
```

adding "static" to index()

I get this error

```
Compilation error
value index is not a member of controllers.Application
.../conf/routes:6
4 # ~~~~
5 # Home page
6 GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
```

I don't know why because in all examples used static for Result

Comment: Do you know what `static`means in a OOP language? Apparently the `index` member of the base class (the field, not the method) is an instance member and therefore cannot be accessed statically.

Comment: @Kryptos: What do you want to say? index() isn't accessed in any way here, static or non-static. The reason is that Play switched to non-static action methods since version 2.4.

Comment: @Kris, you're mistaking `index` for `index()`.

Comment: @Kryptos: There is neither an index nor an index() in [Controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/api/java/play/mvc/Controller.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably still using legacy-style routing.

From the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection):

> Injected routes generator
>   By default, Play will generate a static router, that assumes that all actions are static methods. By configuring Play to use the injected routes generator, you can get Play to generate a router that will declare all the controllers that it routes to as dependencies, allowing your controllers to be dependency injected themselves.
>
> We recommend always using the injected routes generator, the static routes generator exists primarily as a tool to aid migration so that existing projects don’t have to make all their controllers non static at once.
>
> To enable the injected routes generator, add the following to your build settings in build.sbt:
>
> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

Alternatively, you can stick with the static router (but if you're creating a new app, why would you?) and prefix the action reference with a @

```
GET        /some/path        @controllers.Application.index()
```

Comment: In my code the index method in controller is non-static still my application is working. How non-static methods can be called from class name.

Comment: What you write in the `routes` file is not an invocation of a method. `routes` is actually a Scala DSL and is compiled.  When required, the named method will be invoked on an instance of the named class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918001/java-play-application-running-despite-of-having-errors-how-to-resolve-this-erro/41921400?noredirect=1#comment71039546_41921400

can you answer this question?

Answer (score 6):

In Play 2.5 injected routes are used by default. If you still want to use static routes add this to your build.sbt:

```
routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator
```

The `@controllers.…` notation didn't work for me.

More details here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Routes-generated-with-InjectedRoutesGenerator

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.4 changed the default routes generator to InjectedRoutesGenerator to use Dependency Injection for routes. At least tjhat is what is set up in the play-java template.
If you want to still use the static way comment the following line in your build.sbt file

```
// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
//routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 guide > Dependency Injection > Routing for details