# Java play application running despite of having errors- how to resolve this errors?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I just started with play using activator, I created new play app using

```
activator new firstApp play-java
```

Then I opened play console using activator and run the application, app was running fine.
Then I opened the project in my intellij as SBT, the project opened and started showing errors.

in routes file there were lines

```
GET     /                        controllers.HomeController.index
GET     /count                   controllers.CountController.count
GET     /message                 controllers.AsyncController.message
```

This errors are because method index, count and message are not static.
This is an obvious error since we cannot call to static method like this, why the code application is still running.

another error I am getting is in code

```
actorSystem.scheduler().scheduleOnce(
        Duration.create(time, timeUnit),
        () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
        exec
    );
```

It says this is an ambiguous method call.

**My question is, if there are errors why application is running without**

I created run configuration as SBT task and tried to run the app an I got bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me:

Open file root\build.sbt and click 'Import Project' or 'Refresh Project'.
Open file project\plugins.sbt and click 'Import Project' or 'Refresh Project'.

This will import all required libraries and after completing libraries will be visible under project view pane 'External Libraries' tree.

Go to File > Settings, select 'Play2' under 'Languages & Frameworks'.
Under right side Compiler tab check 'Use Play 2 compiler for this project' and Apply settings.

Comment: why is application running even after having the errors. What is happening under the hood.

Comment: Its activator that take care of compilation. Once you map app dependencies and mark application compiler then IDE will be able to link resources.

Comment: Have you downloaded all jars? i have just downloaded all dependencies for firstApp and its working.
Edit : are you able to see list of libraries in 'External Libraries'

Comment: yes everything is fine, application is working. I want to know the reason for the error and how we are able to access non-static methods through class name.

Comment: This is because of Injected-routes-generator  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Injected-routes-generator also use run configuration as Play 2 App